# rails call class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, console

I have my rails app. I have class

```
 class ParserPlugin < ApplicationController
   def self.loadPlugins
     Dir.foreach("/plugins") do |f|
       if f != '.' and f != '..'
         load("/plugins" + f.to_s)
       end
     end
   end
   def self.createplugin
     @@plugins << self.new
   end
 end
```

And I start project with "rails c". And if I try to call "ParserPlugin.loadPlugins" it shows

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ParserPlugin
```

Can you give me some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the file name matches the class name. The file name for:

```
class ParserPlugin < ...
```

should be `parser_plugin.rb` otherwise you'll get the error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ParserPlugin
```

I'm assuming the file is in `/app/controllers` because it's inheriting from the `ApplicationController` class.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses lazy loading, meaning it parses your constants as they appear and looks for a file that matches. Not all of your classes are loaded at startup - this happens the first time you try to access `ParserPlugin`. In this case, Rails is looking for a file called `parser_plugin.rb` in one of your autoloaded directories (probably `controllers`, based on the inheritance you've set up).

A side note: this most likely should not inherit from `ApplicationController`. If it's not a controller, it shouldn't be connected to your controllers. Put it somewhere else.